# Using marker's radius in highcharts for points

Tags: highcharts

I am using markers in my charts and using point chart only. Now when I am using radius to 10 then point starts from given xvalue - 5 and spans till xvalue + 5. I want point to start from xvalue and spans till xvalue + 10. 
Actually left most points are going beyond chart's left extreme and that looks bad.

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3tP5/

```
marker : {
                enabled : true,
                radius : 10,
                symbol: 'square'
            }
```

Comment: Is your real question how to get the points to show up five pixels to the right or how to get the data to not show up on the y-axis labels?

Comment: How to get the points show up five pixel to right.

Comment: Actually. here is another jsfiddle in which http://jsfiddle.net/tRZz5/4/ left most point is going beyond left limit of chart and that looks ugly thats why I want to start it just from the exact xaxis value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of changing the location of each point, this solution will work better:

For your fiddle in the comment, add `yAxis` label config like this [[Link Here]](http://jsfiddle.net/tRZz5/6/):

```
yAxis: {
    offset: 20,
    labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: 0,
        y: 3
    }
},
```

And for the fiddle in your question, a config like this would look pretty nice [[Link Here]](http://jsfiddle.net/v3tP5/1/):

```
yAxis: {
    offset: 8,
    labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3,
        y: 3
    },
    showLastLabel: true
},
```

Hopefully this will work for what you're trying to do. If there are other configs you would like to add or if you have other questions, I will try to help!